# Show more than 30 attachments in document?

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I am using a "document library" (template: StdXLWebXDocLib).
I can record more than 30 files(attachment) in the same document, but I can only see 30. 
Even if I change the Row value.

Is this a XPAGES bug ? 
Anyone know the solution?

(with the Notes client, I see them all)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search in database for string "xp:fileDownload" in Designer. It will show you as result:

[image]

Replace in all three design elements `rows="30"` with `rows="0"`. Then it will show always all attachments.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I had already tried with "0", "60" etc ... 
<xp:fileDownload id="fileDownload23"
    displayLastModified="false" styleClass="files" allowDelete="false"
    hideWhen="true" value="#{currentRowDoc.Body}" rows="0">
</xp:fileDownload>
nothing changes.
Hence my call for help.
At first, as it's an IBM "template", it should work, no. I would not change it.

Comment: Thank you Herrmann , I did not change all parts; it works very well.

Comment: You're welcome. I am glad it works for you after changing *all* occurrences.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik the default entries per page of the xpages repeat element (which might be used in this case) is 30. They might just not have added a pager to it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that template but if you mean the File Download control you can set the value of the lines to display to 0 to not restrict them so that you can see all attachments available.
You can find that property in "All properties, data, rows".